# How to concatenate files found by the find command in bash

Tags: command-line, bash

Searching for files using the bash `find` command, I would like to concatenate the resulting files into a new file. For example, if the find command yields:

```
find . -name "configuration_dev.txt"

./tmp/configuration1/configuration_dev.txt
./tmp/configuration2/configuration_dev.txt
```

I would like to concatenate the contents of the two files into a new file directly as a bash command.

Comment: I don't know really know how to do it, but you could try to use `cat` command which take `find` output, and do a redirect to a `.txt` file with `>` operand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command to achieve the desired result is:

```
find . -name "configuration_dev.txt" -exec cat > testing.txt {} +
```

A good explanation of the above line is provided here: [What is meaning of {} + in find's -exec command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195939/what-is-meaning-of-in-finds-exec-command)

Comment: The  `> cat testing.txt` part can be put anywhere in the command. I'd put it in the beginning or the end, feels more natural, but maybe it's just me... But anyways, this is the way to do it! +1

Comment: Add `-type f` to avoid error messages if your `find` includes directories.

Comment: This probably fails with a large number of files because `cat > testing.txt {}` will be called more than once, overriding the previous contents of the file each time.

Comment: @danzel That's not a problem, it just looks like it would be, due to the confusing placement of `> cat testing.txt`. As pLumo says, it's clearer to put it at the beginning or end of the whole command. The key is, *`> cat testing.txt` is not actually part of any command run by `find`*. `find` never sees `> cat testing.txt`. The shell applies that redirection to the command `find . -name "configuration_dev.txt" -exec cat {} +`. No matter how many times `find` runs `cat`--as you say, with enough files this happens multiple times--`testing.txt` is opened only once, when the shell opens it.

Answer (score 5):

One possible way to do this is by piping the output of `find` to `xargs` and concatenate the content of the files by `cat`, then you can redirect the output to a new file:

```
find . -name '*file*' | xargs -I{} cat "{}" > output
```

The above command will call `cat` for each file and then the entire output of the  `xargs` statement will be redirected to the `output` file. The more effective way is to use null delimiter - thanks to [@pLumo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/plumo) for this update:

```
find . -name '*file*' -print0 | xargs -0 cat > output
```

Comment: This will call `cat` for each file, you could just use `xargs -0 cat`.

Comment: Don't forget xarg's `-r` flag. Running a command when no files were found is often Not Good.

Answer (score 0):

You can also open multiple files in `cat` and redirect the output to a new file. Since the names of multiple files would be returned by `find`, you can use that inside `cat` using `` ` ``(backtick):

```
cat `find . -name "configuration_dev.txt"` > testing.txt
```

Command between backticks would be executed and replaced by the output of the command removing the trailing new line character and inserting a whitespace.

You can confirm this by running

```
A=`find . -name "configuration_dev.txt"`
echo $A
```

As you'll find that the output would be something like:

```
./tmp/configuration/configuration_dev.txt ./tmp/configuration/configuration_dev.txt
```

Thus the actual `cat` command under the hood will be:

```
cat ./tmp/configuration/configuration_dev.txt ./tmp/configuration/configuration_dev.txt > testing.txt
```

Comment: This fails with spaces somewhere along the path  ...

Comment: @pLumo I understand. Thank you for the comment. As of now I have no idea to remove this limitation using the current approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Rust tool [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd), which is a user-friendly alternative to `find`, makes this quite easy.

```
fd -X cat \; "configuration_dev.txt" . > output
```

`-X` is a batch executation of a command on all search results at once. The nice thing about this ([since v8.4.0](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd/releases/tag/v8.4.0)) is that it will not fail with the error `Argument list too long`.